# DateTime, String comparison

Tags: c++, datetime, time, arduino, real-time-clock

I need to compare incoming strings with the date and time from the DS1307 RTC module. I am going to trigger an event if the certain time from the strings are reached.

I've tried using convert to integer but it does not work.

```
String now_int = rtc.now();
```

Error says `conversion from DateTime to non-scalar type String is requested`

How can I compare datetime with a string?

Comment: `now()` returns a `DateTime` object not a string or an int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to datetime in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781852/how-to-convert-a-string-to-datetime-in-c)

Comment: can you post your complete example, especially the comparison you are intending to perform?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) and [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to achieve your described behaviour e.g. similar to [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=290342.msg2030584#msg2030584)

```
// date and time from RTC
DateTime now = rtc.now();

// date and time to compare with - this is provided by you
String datetimeCompare = "1970/01/01 00:00:00";

// this buffer must be big enough for your complete datetime (depending on the format)
char datetimeBuffer[20] = "";

// convert current date and time to your specific format
sprintf(datetimeBuffer, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", now.year(), now.month(), now.day(), now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());

// perform the comparison
if(strcmp(datetimeBuffer, datetimeCompare.c_str()) == 0)
{
    // datetime strings are the same
}
```

Or you convert your rtc.now() DateTime according to your format as described over at the [arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/4803).